# Definition of business logic and application logic in MVC/OOP

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I'm learning MVC and OOP, but something has me confused:

**What is the difference between business and application logic?**

Take a look at the following scenario of a payment and invoicing system:

Customers are invoiced, and when they pay the invoice it is acknowledged via a payments on the screen. The user enters the amount they have received from the customer into the system.

Now, is application logic the following (in the controller):

- User can not enter negative numbers
- User must enter input in the style of integers only or #.# or #.## or
  ##.## etc.

Business logic (in the model):

- The amount entered can not exceed the amount on the invoice (ie
  what's due)
- And/or the amount entered can not exceed the amount owed if part
  payments have been made previously

Do I have the right idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should put all business logic, including that for formatting and validation into the model. So not entering a negative number is a focus for the model not the controller. Read up on [Skinny Controller, Fat Model](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model) and maybe the presenter pattern using [Draper](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper). Ryan Bates has covered a fair amount of this stuff recently on [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com). Probably good to look into that too.

Answer (score 0):

Business logic means rules that cannot violate your business process. The last two examples you give are business logic because these rules depend on the business and not the application.

Application logic is logic that isn't related to the business. For instance making sure the first two rules are enforced because they would violate the second two rules you listed.

My 2 cents anyways.

So yes, you are on the right track.